# Copying certain index names (strings) to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am wishing to create a new dataframe from certain rows of an existing dataframe. The indexes are string names (eg: 043-095(L01)). I wish to copy all of the rows with an index starting with 043.

I've tried using wildcards to call the rows:

```
df_new = df_old.loc[df_old.index == '043*']
```

This, however, brings up an empty dataframe, only copying the column names.

I then tried a less efficient methos of creating a list of the index names and calling these iteratively through a loop. This also didn't work:

```
list = list(df_old.index.get_values()) 
for i in list: 
    df_new = df_old.loc[df_old.index == i]
```

This produces a dataframe with only the last column from the original dataframe. However, this is an index titled 'over' so does not even fit the filtering I am looking for.

Here is the initial dataframe:

```
                1    2    3    4    5      ...                 36            37            38            39            40
product                                    ...                                                                           
043-096(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       5.643140e+00  5.340900e+00  5.088400e+00  4.468070e+00  4.092830e+00
041-092(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       2.312400e+01  2.292020e+01  2.166400e+01  2.062450e+01  1.961710e+01
043-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       2.019000e-01  1.145850e+00  6.568850e+00  1.580680e+01  2.964780e+01
041-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       3.929880e+01  3.760480e+01  3.625430e+01  3.542060e+01  3.510910e+01
041-093(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       6.371910e+00  5.821850e+00  5.535770e+00  5.392260e+00  5.291000e+00
043-096(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.750060e+00  1.715700e+00  1.681990e+00  1.358840e+00  1.296470e+00
042-093(L16)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.172700e+00  1.178630e+01  3.434970e+01  7.109020e+01  1.136440e+02
043-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       8.628490e+00  3.177190e+01  7.529960e+01  1.314360e+02  1.981620e+02
041-095(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       8.165380e-03  8.903470e-03  8.237130e-03  8.687170e-03  9.185370e-03
042-093(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.346020e+01  2.028300e+01  2.922050e+01  3.994700e+01  5.241390e+01
043-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.453260e+02  1.051780e+02  7.979190e+01  6.791930e+01  5.806560e+01
043-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       2.359510e+01  2.092200e+01  1.799270e+01  1.547530e+01  1.292230e+01
041-092(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       5.922860e+01  5.580080e+01  5.150720e+01  4.853910e+01  4.493510e+01
041-095(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.530490e-01  1.583970e-01  1.407330e-01  1.371880e-01  1.355580e-01
041-091(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       5.372560e+01  5.788070e+01  6.146730e+01  6.655750e+01  7.144250e+01
041-090(L02)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       0.000000e+00  5.594050e-05  8.369660e-04  2.903470e-03  1.917730e-02
041-090(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       0.000000e+00  1.534300e-03  8.703700e-03  4.770440e-02  1.738080e-01
041-094(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.385020e+00  1.635600e+00  1.817290e+00  2.056140e+00  2.293480e+00
043-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       9.074630e+02  9.164940e+02  8.776860e+02  7.838060e+02  6.768200e+02
041-091(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.810710e+01  2.097550e+01  2.283200e+01  2.553310e+01  2.845680e+01
039-089(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       7.822260e-02  9.664860e-02  1.074630e-01  1.214690e-01  1.348120e-01
043-097(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.754870e-07  7.402690e-08  5.900700e-08  1.725820e-08  1.416280e-08
041-094(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       9.471510e-01  1.195480e+00  1.458680e+00  1.727560e+00  2.054990e+00
039-089(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.983690e-02  2.039220e-02  2.140960e-02  2.252160e-02  2.330300e-02
043-095(L01)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       7.249500e+00  6.697730e+00  6.278970e+00  6.019280e+00  5.670850e+00
043-097(L00)  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       6.121160e-06  1.084730e-06  6.949800e-07  1.232050e-07  1.013090e-07
sum           0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      ...       1.316938e+03  1.325456e+03  1.336783e+03  1.343518e+03  1.362432e+03
over          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN      ...       5.504817e-03  5.053151e-03  4.697077e-03  4.480238e-03  4.162301e-03
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset ?

Comment: Does it alsways start with the string you're trying to match? If so, how about `df.index.str.startswith()`

Comment: @johnnyb I have attached the dataset I wish to filter through. Thanks

Comment: That works, thank you @G.Anderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this to print only the rows your interseted in.  As another commenter added, you can also use startswith in place of str.contains. The more explicit method would be the str.startswith method.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("testdata.txt", header=None)

print(df[df.index.str.contains("043-")]) # string contains version

print(df[df.index.str.startswith("043")]) # index starts with
```